# How to install tcldot library in ubuntu20

Tags: tcl

I need to install Tcldot library and
I installed

- graphviz
- tcl-dev
  in ubuntu 20.
  but there is not **tcldot** library..
  How can I install it in ubuntu?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used **tcldot**, but this documentation (https://graphviz.org/pdf/tcldot.3tcl.pdf) says:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/tclsh
package require Tcldot
```